# Is there a Socket.IO class for Windows 8 C#

Tags: windows-8, socket.io

Is there a Socket.IO client class for Windows 8 Metro in C#?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.networking.sockets.aspx

Comment: Nope not at all.
Socket.io is a websocket based wrapper not normal sockets.